# Unselect the file type when renaming files in XP

Tags: windows-xp, rename, file-extension

In Windows XP the file extension gets selected when renaming a file. If I choose to add that extension to the Known filetypes, it doesn't show the extension but the file type still changes.

For example, whenever I rename a subtitle (and I do that very often, because I use Serviio), I can edit the whole name (Subtitle name and the".srt" extension), not only the name.
I have seen similar posts, but none worked, I even tried the "The End" program, and nothing.

Thank you

Comment: Did you try an AutoHotKey script? Possible duplicate of [Renaming files using F2 on Windows XP](http://superuser.com/questions/102104/renaming-files-using-f2-on-windows-xp). Also see [Any tool available to make renaming in Windows XP more like Mac OS X?](http://superuser.com/questions/15351/any-tool-available-to-make-renaming-in-windows-xp-more-like-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 0):

How about disabling the '*Hide extensions for know file type*' Windows Explorer feature - personally I hate it anyway, but with it disabled, you can see the whole filename (including extension) and can chose if/when to change that extension.

Or you can extend XPs behaviour with a utility like [AutoHotKey](http://lifehacker.com/355580/mimic-vistas-file-rename-feature-in-xp).